# Can a google cloud bigtable table have just a rowkey?

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

Given a table with no column family since we want to store only the rowkey,

```
cbt ls alert_lut
Family Name     GC Policy
-----------     ---------
```

and an input file

```
head file.csv
185418825#1#ANT2018cjdkc
227156697#1#ANT2020jhyg4
3382811056#1#ANT2021kr2f2
54520783939#1#ANT2020wlymk
52841617510#1#ANT2019csrqk
49914774751#1#ANT2019ankba
266967569#1#ANT2020sqdmm
266967569#1#ANT2022643j2nii6jc8
53038301733#1#ANT2021vje4w
```

when running `cbt import alert_lut file.csv` it returns

```
2022/10/17 12:15:44 error parsing headers: at least 2 columns are required (rowkey + data)
```

I've tried adding a columnfamily and using

```
head file.csv
,
185418825#1#ANT2018cjdkc,
227156697#1#ANT2020jhyg4,
3382811056#1#ANT2021kr2f2,
54520783939#1#ANT2020wlymk,
52841617510#1#ANT2019csrqk,
49914774751#1#ANT2019ankba,
```

and it returns

```
2022/10/17 12:22:18 error parsing headers: the first column must be empty for column-family and column name rows
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bigtable tables do require a column family and column. One common approach for developers in this situation is to just use a single character for each. This takes up the least amount of space possible and shouldn't add too much extra overhead.

An example would be column family `a` and column `a`